# Using CSS Selectors Incorrectly

Tags: html, css

I have some code that looks like below.  I am using css to try and assign the span tag with `id="TL_QUANTITY$0"` with `padding-right of 20px`.  But I'm using the CSS selectors incorrectly.  Does anyone know how I would change the end of the css to assign that span tag with that padding by not directly calling that id?

Here is the HTML:

```
    <td id="tdTL_PAYABLE_TIME$0#2" class="PSLEVEL1GRIDODDROW" width="127" align="left" style="">
    <td id="tdTL_PAYABLE_TIME$0#3" class="PSLEVEL1GRIDODDROW" width="152" align="left" style="">
    <td id="tdTL_PAYABLE_TIME$0#5" class="PSLEVEL1GRIDODDROW" width="105" align="left" style="">
    <td id="tdTL_PAYABLE_TIME$0#6" class="PSLEVEL1GRIDODDROW" align="right" style="">

<div id="win10divTL_QUANTITY$0" style="width:78px;">
    <span id="TL_QUANTITY$0" class="PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY">8.00</span></div></td>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#lbContent #comp_zPNCComp .PSLEVEL1GRIDODDROW, #lbContent #comp_zPNCComp .PSLEVEL2GRIDODDROW, #lbContent #comp_zPNCComp .PSLEVEL3GRIDODDROW, #lbContent #comp_zPNCComp .PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW div:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(1) {
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

I know this much of it is correct, I just am messing up where I try calling the children:

```
#lbContent #comp_zPNCComp .PSLEVEL1GRIDODDROW, #lbContent #comp_zPNCComp .PSLEVEL2GRIDODDROW, #lbContent #comp_zPNCComp .PSLEVEL3GRIDODDROW, #lbContent #comp_zPNCComp .PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW
```

Comment: This code is just AWFUL. Only a wysiwyg editor can make such a thing. Why don't you use something readable as classes and IDs, and stop combining inline and external styles?

Comment: I did not build the code.  It was already designed like this.  Can you please help me find a solution to the question.

Comment: Can someone please help?  Surely there is still a way to come to the solution I need..

Answer (score 2):

I think the real problem is with the id names for the elements. I may be wrong, but I don't think the use of `$` is allowed in CSS to specify an element's id name.

See here: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: correct.  but that is how the application works.  I'm trying to find a way around it

Comment: @Mark +1 Missed it.  my eyes didn't catch the `$ and #` :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, `ID`s are meant for **unique selector**

whereas `class` is for a **group of elements**.

**Update:** First I missed to catch `$` and `#`, which are not allowed.

Option1: ID selector

```
#ElementId {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Option2: Using your div's ID or class

```
#classID {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Option3: Using Pseudo selector like  [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VZu7N/), in your case you can try something similar to this.

```
div:last-child span{
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Still more options available.

Comment: how would I apply this to the css i have?

Answer (score 0):

Your ID element selector is invalid "id="tdTL_PAYABLE_TIME$0#2". "$" is not allowed in ID

Answer (score 0):

Having the hashes (`#`) in your ID names will cause errors, for example:

`#tdTL_PAYABLE_TIME$0#6` says `any element with ID 'tdTL_PAYABLE_TIME$0' and also ID '6'`.

You could try:

```
.PSSRCHRESULTSODDROW div[style="width:78px;"]:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(1)
```

Comment: Where are you getting the width:78 from?  I need to assign the innermost tag which is the span tag a padding-right of 20px...

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood. I thought you wanted to target specifically that `span`, not all first `span`s in the first `div` of a `td`. I was taking the `width:78px;` attribute selector from the div above it (ID `win10divTL_QUANTITY$0`). **Edit:** You might consider using the `:first-of-type` pseudo-selector too.

Comment: I'm targeting the span tag and wanting to apply on padding-right:20px; to that one.  Please help if you can

Comment: Just that one `span` tag? What's wrong with using an ID or a class selector? `.PSLEVEL1GRIDODDROW div span.PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY`